# Why do we have a “german” tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that for some reason there is a [german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german) tag. It seems rather pointless to me and thus I would suggest to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely right, of course. We're blacklisting the [german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german) tag internally, effective immediately, so people won't be able to create it anew in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The [german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german) tag was introduced a long time ago (don't know who did it) and many people used it. I remember Takkat asking the very same question in chat a while ago. At that time, he removed that tag from any questions that were using it.

I'm afraid but people were using it again of late. Unfortunately, we cannot ban this tag and it's easily recreated any time.

However, it doesn't make sense at all, and we should remove it from all questions.

Comment: Thank you for removing it again...

Comment: Looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags I would expect the tag to be gone if nobody uses it again by 3 o'clock this night. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Matthias I thought that it would be around longer before it get deleted. However, if that's true, it was removed but reintroduced. And I'm pretty sure it'll happen again.

Comment: @Em1 Looks like it's actually gone: http://german.stackexchange.com/tags?page=3&tab=name If it should really get reintroduced we could discuss whether to keep it, but give it a clear "DEPRECATED" description.